# Proportions for multiple subcategories

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to calculate proportions with multiple subcategories. As seen in the screenshot below, the series is grouped by ['budget_levels', 'revenue_levels'].
I would like to calculate the proportion for each.

[image]

For example,

```py
budget_levels=='low' & revenue_levels=='low' / budget_levels=='low'
budget_levels=='low' & revenue_levels=='medium' / budget_levels=='low'
```

However, not getting the desired output.

Is there any way I could do this calculation for each with a simple one-line code such as .apply(lambda) function?

Answer (score 0):

Use `value_counts` to get the number of occurences of each combination. Then group by the column `budget_levels` and divide the observations in each group by their sum. `sort_index` makes it easier to compare the groups.

```
df.value_counts().groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: x / x.sum()).sort_index()
```